# Best practice to reach properties dynamically?

Tags: c#, dynamic, properties

I have a class:

```
public class ActionReportEntity
{
    public string Caption { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Item1 { get; set; }
    public string Item2 { get; set; }
    public string Item3 { get; set; }
    public string Item4 { get; set; }
    public string Item5 { get; set; }
    public string Item6 { get; set; }
    public string Item7 { get; set; }
    public string Item8 { get; set; }
    public string Item9 { get; set; }
    public string Item10 { get; set; }
}
```

I want to fill Item1 to Item(1-10) dynamically, I achieve this properties with this code:

```
Regex regex=new Regex("Item[0-9]+");
var props = typeof(ActionReportEntity)
.GetProperties()
.Where(p => regex.IsMatch(p.Name))
.OrderBy(p=>p.Name.Substring(4).ToInteger());
```

But i think this way is not good and powerful because may be any one  refactor this class and add some property abrupt like Item50 or change a property.

I think i must be use **attribute**, but i don't use it yet.

*What is best practice to achieve dynamic properties?*

**Update:**

**Mentioned that I want to use this class in binding in grid or report, So i don't want change structure of my class, Because i can't bind list prop to grid or used it in report**

Answer (score 1):

And then, the Almighty Programmer invented `List<>`, who came from the family of `IEnumerable`. He also stated, "thou shalt not iterate over hardcoded variable names". And there was much to rejoice about :)

Just make a `public List<string> Items { get; set; }` and add all your strings there, this makes your life easier in every possible way.

Comment: +1 for  "thou shalt not iterate over hardcoded variable names"

Comment: I mentioned that I want to use this class in binding in grid or report, So i don't want change structure of my class,because i can't bind list prop to grid or use in report.

Comment: A report not being able to handle a IEnumerable? Either way, you would always ADD the IEnumerable to your class. When you need to iterate, you can copy all your Item# variables into the list, iterate ove the list, then copy them back (you'll only have to write a 'copy' and 'put back' algorithm. It will work perfectly, But I do feel that not being able to process an IEnumerable means you have a bigger underlying issue...

Comment: Suppose i have a grid, how to bind a list of properties to grid?

Comment: That is a realy open question. Are you using MVC3, MVC2, a regular datagrid, ... I can't answer that without getting a deeper understanding of your problem, which I think might be going out of scope for the question at hand. in general: use IEnumerables. I advise againt hardcoded variables, but if you must, you can still use the IEnumerable as a temporary storage for preocessing the variables, then copying them back to their originale variable.

Comment: OK, I have a DataGridView in windows form, also my main intention of this question is how to distinguish dynamic properties from other(i think attribute can do it but i don't know how?).

Comment: Any issue related to know knowing how many items are in you list can be solved by either myList.Count or using foreach(var item in myList) {...}

Comment: So when iterate on list and add column to grid, Now what is column datamember for each column?

Comment: Last comment because this is getting too long :) Do you have AutoGenerateColumns turned on? Then your DataGridView will automatically generate columns for you for all items. You can find more info on this if you Google "DataGridView List", you're not the first one having questions about this :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to store them in some simple data structure.

Answer (score 0):

I know you have indicated that you don't want to change your class structure, but are you open to changing the internal structure of the class without changing the public structure?  If so, you could leave the properties as-is, and just use an array as a backing field.  You could them provide an `Update` method to update individual properties by index or update all 10 at once.

```
public class ActionReportEntity
{
    private String[] items = new String[10];

    public string Caption { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Item1 { get { return items[0]; } set { items[0] = value; } }
    public string Item2 { get { return items[1]; } set { items[1] = value; } }
    public string Item3 { get { return items[2]; } set { items[2] = value; } }
    public string Item4 { get { return items[3]; } set { items[3] = value; } }
    public string Item5 { get { return items[4]; } set { items[4] = value; } }
    public string Item6 { get { return items[5]; } set { items[5] = value; } }
    public string Item7 { get { return items[6]; } set { items[6] = value; } }
    public string Item8 { get { return items[7]; } set { items[7] = value; } }
    public string Item9 { get { return items[8]; } set { items[8] = value; } }
    public string Item10 { get { return items[9]; } set { items[9] = value; } }

    public void UpdateItem(Int32 index, String value)
    {
        if (index >= items.Length)
            throw new ArgumentException();

        items[index] = value;
    }
    public void UpdateItem(params String[] values)
    {
        if (values.Length != items.Length)
            throw new ArgumentException();

        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
        {
            items[i] = values[i];                
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,but use of list how to help me?